# How to query a DataTable in memory to fill another data table

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, reporting-services

I am trying to update a Microsoft report. What it does is write out how many clients where excluded from a conversion process and for what reason. Currently the program writes all of the deleted clients back to the server then queries it back to fill a specialty table with the results.

Here is the current query:

```
SELECT  DeletedClients.Reason, 
        COUNT(DeletedClients.Reason) AS Number, 
        CAST(CAST(COUNT(DeletedClients.Reason) AS float) 
            / CAST(t.Total AS float) 
            * 100 AS numeric(4, 1)) AS percentage
FROM DeletedClients CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total
    FROM DeletedClients AS DeletedClients_1
    WHERE (ClinicID = @ClinicID)) AS t
WHERE (DeletedClients.ClinicID = @ClinicID) 
    AND (DeletedClients.TotalsIdent = @ident)
GROUP BY DeletedClients.Reason, t.Total
ORDER BY Number DESC
```

What I would like to do is not write `DeletedClients` to the server as it already exists in memory in my program as a DataTable and it is just slowing down the report and filling the database with information we do not need to save.

**My main question is this, Either :**

How do I query a data table to make a new in memory data table that has the same results as if I wrote out the the SQL server and read it back in with the query above?

**OR**

How in Microsoft Reports do you do a group by clause for items in a Tablix to turn `=Fields!Reason.Value` `=Fields!Number.Value` `=Fields!percentage.Value` into something similar to the returned result from the query above?

Comment: More examples here - dotnetperls.com/datatable-select Select("Size >= 230 AND Sex = 'm'"); Select("Date > #6/1/2001#");

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use DataTable.Select to query the DataTable.

```
DataTable table = GetDataTableResults();
DataTable results = table.Select("SomeIntColumn > 0").CopyToDataTable();
```

Or for more complex queries, you can use LINQ to query the DataTable:

```
DataTable dt = GetDataTableResults();

var results = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
              group row by new { SomeIDColumn = row.Field<int>("SomeIDColumn") } into rowgroup
              select new
              {
                  SomeID = rowgroup.Key.SomeIDColumn,
                  SomeTotal = rowgroup.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("SomeDecimalColumn"))
              };                    

DataTable queryResults = new DataTable();
foreach (var result in query)
    queryResults.Rows.Add(new object[] { result.SomeID, result.SomeTotal });
```

Comment: Using LINQ or DataTable.Select how do I use the Group by clause? as that is the main problem I am having translating.

Comment: With LINQ you can, but I don't think it's possible with DataTable.Select. I think you can do some basic grouping with DataTable.Compute, but it's limited. If you're looking to group information in code, LINQ is your best bet.

Comment: Can you show a example of how to write a LINQ using group by?

Comment: It appears to all work perfectly except the CopyToDataTable. I get the error `The type 'AnonymousType#1' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'AnonymousType#1' to 'System.Data.DataRow'.`

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain: I've updated my answer. CopyToDataTable was more elegant, but the manual loading technique should work just fine too.

Comment: @JamesJohnson - Sorry, your method did not work for me. I cannot import the necessary dlls. Can you help me to figure it out here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308852/copy-selected-data-from-datatable-to-another-datatable . Also, will your method work if the necessary DLL is missing from the system ?

Comment: @Trojan.ZBOT: I think `System.Data` is the only reference required to use this code, and if you can't import that namespace there may be a bigger issue you need to deal with. Like the `System` namespace, `System.Data` is pretty much required for data-driven development in .NET.

Comment: @JamesJohnson - I am not sure if that is the case. I tried the steps given to me in a question and things are working now. Here is the question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308852/copy-selected-data-from-datatable-to-another-datatable I wonder if I am missing something.

Comment: @Trojan.ZBOT: The answer on that question suggested adding a reference to the `System.Data` assembly, which it looks like you did. Assuming that Linq is where its breaking, try adding a reference to `System.Data.Linq` and/or `System.Linq` also.

Comment: More examples here - http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable-select

Select("Size >= 230 AND Sex = 'm'");
Select("Date > #6/1/2001#");

Comment: @JamesJohnson - I got the error 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'CopyToDataTable' and no extension method 'CopyToDataTable' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Is there a pre .NET 3.5 way to do this ? I am not able to  import the .net dll needed - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005555/error-in-selecting-from-a-datatable-and-copying-the-datatable

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways that I can think of to query the data table.  Below is an example using both ways.

```
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            var deletedClients = GetDataTable();

            // Using linq to create the new DataTable.
            var example1 = deletedClients.AsEnumerable()
                                         .Where(x => x.Field<int>("ClinicId") == 1)
                                         .CopyToDataTable();

            // Using the DefaultView RowFilter to create a new DataTable.
            deletedClients.DefaultView.RowFilter = "ClinicId = 1";
            var rowFilterExample = deletedClients.DefaultView.ToTable();
        }

        static DataTable GetDataTable()
        {
            var dataTable = new DataTable();
            // Assumes ClinicId is an int...
            dataTable.Columns.Add("ClinicId", typeof(int));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Reason");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(int));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Percentage", typeof(float));

            for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)
            {
                dataTable.Rows.Add(counter, "Reason" + counter, counter, counter);
            }

            return dataTable;
        }
    }
}
```