# Copy selected data from DataTable to another DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to select some of the data from a datatable and copy it into another data table. I found the answer in one question - [How to query a DataTable in memory to fill another data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109268/how-to-query-a-datatable-in-memory-to-fill-another-data-table)

```
DataTable table = GetDataTableResults();
DataTable results = table.Select("SomeIntColumn > 0").CopyToDataTable();
```

This code does not work and causes the error -

```
'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'CopyToDataTable' and 
no extension method 'CopyToDataTable' accepting a first argument of type 
'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or 
an assembly reference?)
```

I am using visual studio 2008 and .net 3.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have the right references. In this you need System.Data.DataSetExtensions Assembly and  System.Data Namespace. The following link should help...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189(v=vs.110).aspx

Good Luck!

EDIT: Screenshot of Reference...

[image]

Comment: Does not work. I tried that link before posting the question. I cannot find the System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll in my references menu.

Comment: I see it in my menu. I think this library is available only in .NET 3.5 and above

Comment: I still cannot see it in my menu. Also, can you post a bigger image please ? I tried clicking yours, but it wont become big.  Thanks.

Comment: Updated  the image. Any better?

Comment: Thanks, the image is much clearer now. My GUI is a bit different from yours. I have a window with tabs for .NET, Com, Projects, Browse and Recent. I could not find this DLL mentioned there.

Comment: I found System.Data.DataSetExtensions version 3.5 and runtime is ver 2.xx. It is in gray color and it says that its not compatible with the specified .NET version.

Comment: I think as long as you have .NET 3.5 you should be able to see the required assembly.

Comment: I think I need to make my project compatible with .NET 3.5 and upwards. I remember having seen that minimum set to 2.0 somewhere. I can't remember how to change it. Can you tell me how ? Thanks.

Comment: The following link should walk you through the process changing the target .NET framework version...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398202(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can always just loop through the array of `DataRow` objects returned from `Select()` and import them into the new data table, like this:

```
DataTable table = GetDataTableResults();
DataTable results;

DataRow[] rowArray = table.Select("SomeIntColumn > 0");

foreach (DataRow row in rowArray) 
{
    results.ImportRow(row);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me an alternate way. But, I prefer to do it without using rows.