# Error in selecting from a Datatable and copying the DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I tried to sort a datatable. To do that, you sort it and then copy the sorted one into a datatable, as shown here - [How to query a DataTable in memory to fill another data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109268/how-to-query-a-datatable-in-memory-to-fill-another-data-table)

code -

```
DataTable table = GetDataTableResults();
DataTable results = table.Select("SomeIntColumn > 0").CopyToDataTable();
```

In visual studio, i see the error -

```
'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'CopyToDataTable' and 
no extension method 'CopyToDataTable' accepting a first argument of type 
'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an 
assembly reference?)
```

How do I fix this ?

Comment: I got the answer - 
Note that a .NET dll is different from a native DLL. This one is a .NET dll.
Steps to add this .NET dll - 

solution explorer > references > .NET tab > under component name column, select System.Data.DataSetExtensions > ok > file > save all or ctrl + shift + s

Comment: System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll missing - solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add reference to **System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll** in your project.

[How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Add Reference Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

Comment: This would be a .NET Assembly DLL, right ? How do I find where this DLL is located ?

Comment: Yes, it's framework assembly. You should see it under *Assemblies/Framework*.

Comment: Note that a .NET dll is different from a native DLL. This one is a .NET dll.
Steps to add this .NET dll - 

solution explorer > references > .NET tabl > under component name column, select System.Data.DataSetExtensions > ok > file > save all or ctrl + shift + s

Answer (score 1):

Which framework are you using? If I'm not wrong, CopyToDataTable is supported only in ver. 3.5 and above.

Comment: But this page says 3.5 and above - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @SonerGönül - I changed my target framework to .net 3.5. Now trying to find the missing DLL